# why concurrent mode failure when there were still enough memory in old memory

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Our service had a full GC.This is the first full GC since the service started.
When the full GC happened, there were still enough free memory in old memory.
So I want to know how it happened and how to fix it.

```
2017-03-09T08:27:18.757+0800: 80101.423: [GC 80101.423: [ParNew: 441137K->22010K(471872K), 0.0133050 secs] 1090097K->670970K(2044736K), 0.0134350 secs] [Times: user=0.07 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
2017-03-09T08:28:43.053+0800: 80185.720: [GC 80185.720: [ParNew: 441466K->22372K(471872K), 0.0146790 secs] 1090426K->671332K(2044736K), 0.0148100 secs] [Times: user=0.07 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2017-03-09T08:29:01.133+0800: 80203.799: [Full GC 80203.799: [CMS (concurrent mode failure)[YG occupancy: 122632 K (471872 K)]80204.163: [weak refs processing, 0.0011100 secs]80204.164: [scrub string table, 0.0017900 secs]: 648959K->313273K(1572864K), 0.5230930 secs] 771592K->435905K(2044736K), [CMS Perm : 136619K->136619K(136832K)], 0.5233420 secs] [Times: user=0.84 sys=0.00, real=0.53 secs] 
2017-03-09T08:30:06.668+0800: 80269.334: [GC 80269.335: [ParNew: 441828K->18343K(471872K), 0.0164870 secs] 755102K->331616K(2044736K), 0.0166300 secs] [Times: user=0.08 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2017-03-09T08:31:52.787+0800: 80375.454: [GC 80375.454: [ParNew: 437799K->21566K(471872K), 0.0137290 secs] 751072K->334840K(2044736K), 0.0138540 secs] [Times: user=0.07 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
```

java version: 1.7.0_25,64 bit

```
-Xmn512M 
-Xmx2048M 
-Xms2048M 
-XX:MaxPermSize=256M 
-XX:PermSize=128M 
-XX:SurvivorRatio=8 
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC 
-XX:CMSFullGCsBeforeCompaction=50 
-XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection 
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC 
-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=30 
-verbose:gc 
-XX:+PrintGCDetails 
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps 
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps 
-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal
```

Comment: you should add `-XX:+PrintGCCause` or  upgrade to 1.8 where it's the default

Comment: The parameter -XX:+PrintGCCause was introduced within Java 1.7.0_45。I can not use it in our java version. I can not change the java version. Is there any other way to find out the cause of the full gc?

Comment: "I can not change the java version." ... I suggest you reconsider that if you care about solving this issue

Comment: There are no lines related to concurrent collection, which is expect to be in GC log. Could you please extend log excerpt? I also see your PremGen is full. Full PermGen is common problem for CMS GC, your should either increase PermGen, or configure separate Perm occupancy threshold for CMS.

Comment: I had increased PermGen to 256m last week. Since then no major GC happened.Thanks.